# Service function can't access 'this' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When I affect a function and call it, the variable `this` is undefine, so the `this.http.get...`  is in error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined`

```
const getFacilityEventsFunction = this.isPastActivated
      ? this.facilityService.getPastTimelineFacilities
      : this.facilityService.getFutureTimelineFacilities;
    this.facilityEvents$ = getFacilityEventsFunction(this.iteration);
```

Also, when I remove the logic with the function in a const and do a call with a classic if else, it works

```
if (this.isPastActivated) {
  this.facilityEvents$ = this.facilityService.getPastTimelineFacilities(0);
} else {
  this.facilityEvents$ = this.facilityService.getFutureTimelineFacilities(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store a function in a variable, you have to bind the owner of it this way, otherwise it doesn't remember where it comes from:

```
const getFacilityEventsFunction = this.isPastActivated
      ? this.facilityService.getPastTimelineFacilities.bind(this.facilityService)
      : this.facilityService.getFutureTimelineFacilities.bind(this.facilityService);
    this.facilityEvents$ = getFacilityEventsFunction(this.iteration);
```

Comment: The less repetitive option would probably be `getFacilityEventsFunction.call(this.facilityService, this.iteration)`…

Comment: Your code works, but I dont fint it pretty to handle the injection so I came back to the if else. If you think the bind is better don't hesitate to teach me why tho. Thanks :)